# Shell sort column

Tags: excel, shell, sorting, vba

I'm learning VB all by myself. I got to write code to sort column A:A in Shell method.
I'm stuck on proceeding to next gap (next gap is simply gap/2) after sorting for first N/2 (N is number of cells to sort).

```
Sub Shellsort()

Dim gap As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Obad As Range
Dim N As Long
Dim temp As Long

N = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A:A"))

gap = N


    For i = 1 To gap

        If Cells(i, 1).Value < Cells(i + gap, 1).Value Then

            temp = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + gap, 1).Value
            Cells(i + gap, 1).Value = temp

        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

How should I continue? This code ofc now compares only 2 cells, but I have no idea how make it depend on actual gap.

Answer (score 0):

To proceed to the next gap (and the first gap should probably be `N\2` rather than `N` btw), I'd wrap your loop in a

```
Do While gap > 0
    For i = 1 To gap
        'code
    Next i
    gap = gap \ 2
Loop
```

As for sorting within each interleaved set, you'll probably want to extract this set as an array within the for loop, and apply a (separately implemented) insertion sort on that array.